# C++: Throwing shared_ptr of derived and catching shared_ptr of base?

Tags: c++, exception, shared-ptr

Ok, I've been told this problem: Why can you throw a pointer to a derived class and catch a pointer to its base... but you can't do that with shared_ptrs?

Example, this works:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
int main()
{   
    try 
    {   
        throw new Derived() ;
    }   
    catch( const Base2 * b ) 
    {   
        printf("Received a base" ) ; 
    }   

    return 0 ;
}
```

But this doesn't

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw std::tr1::shared_ptr<Derived>( new Derived() ) ;
    }
    catch( const std::tr1::shared_ptr<Base> & b ) 
    {
        printf("Received a base" ) ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that `shared_ptr<Base>` does not match the signature of `shared_ptr<Derived>` as far as the exception handler cares.

Comment: Why you are using pointer with throw/catch? It's bad practice.

Comment: I can't see a way this would be possible. Not even wrapping with a function that takes a body and handler std::function to compose it generically: you can't catch generically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that your second example doesn't work.

The exception handler will only catch exceptions in very clearly defined ways. In particular, you cannot do an implicit conversion when catching. Only derived-to-base and pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base conversions are applied. Since `shared_ptr<derived>` does not derive from `shared_ptr<base>`, and it is not a built-in pointer, it doesn't match.

If you want to catch `shared_ptr<base>`, then convert to `shared_ptr<base>` before throwing.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is pretty simple: even when `derived` is related to `base`, `shared_ptr<derived>` isn't related to `shared_ptr<base>` so there's no implicit conversion from one to the other unless the template explicitly provides it (and the same applies to essentially any other template instantiated in the same way).

For exceptions, however, I'm not sure what problem you're really trying to solve. Normally, you want to throw an object (not a pointer) and you want to catch a `const` reference. Since you don't have any real possibility of having multiple pointers to the same exception object, I'm not sure what problem you'd solve with a `shared_ptr<exception_object>`.

Comment: Actually, there _is_ an implicit conversion from shared_ptr<Derived> to shared_ptr<Base> as you can do this without trouble
`void func( const shared_ptr<Base> & );
... 
func( shared_ptr<Derived>( new Derived() ) );`